# How to run very expensive jobs and maintain availability

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, amazon-web-services, scalability

I have a scenario where a single client request can result in up to a minute of CPU time being consumed at the server end. Is there any way to ensure that the resources are available for this to be able to scale? I am basically asking if there is a way to invoke a new role instance from code, and to pass it some work. Is this possible in Azure? Or another cloud platform?

Comment: This is a very vague question, you should ask specific questions. It sounds like you need to look at Azure Service Bus its a message queuing system that can process jobs out of process. Again though this question too vague. You need to tell us more about the request and supply code etc

Comment: I am quite clear in what I am asking. What sort of clarification would you like?

Comment: I would recommend reading up on `Cloud Design Patterns` guide on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568099.aspx. This should certainly give you some pointers.

Comment: Sorry. The clarity i am talking about is what the request is actually doing. Is it just loading a view or processing some kind of report or what? The answer to your question kind of depends on this. Does the user need to see the result of the request straight away or can it be processed in the background?

Comment: Based on Request if scaling is done, scaling may be uncontrollable, also scaling hardware is not your business logic... your scaling can be done based on Number Of Requests OR CPU OR Memory, No matter due to what business logic there is a demand for resource. Did you look at Auto scaling features of azure?

Comment: Based on the information here, I'd suggest a classic web/worker role cloud pattern with asynchronous responses to requests. If the work your workers are doing is extensive, you can spin up more workers without negatively impacting the front end availability of your service and you'll achieve a better client experience as well (clients don't want to wait for a minute of CPU time for a response, typically).

Answer (score 1):

You can use AutoScale application block to dynamically scale your cloud service based on certain conditions.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680892(v=pandp.50).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680892%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx)

However I suggest not to scale your service from your business logic using code.
(See my comments on the question)

If you need more monitoring about your service, there are paid Azure addons available. But i would say Autoscale application block may solve your problem.